# Re-writing query from in() to joins

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Can you assist in re-writing this into joins?

```
select * from users where users.advised_by in (
select p.id 
from advisors p
join advisor_members m on p.id = m.advisor_id
join representatives r on m.user_id=r.user_id
where m.memeber_type='Advisor'
)
```

This is part of 200+ row query and that in() statement is hard to maintain when there are changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use a proper  on  clause

```
select * 
from users 
inner join 
(
select p.id 
from advisors p
join advisor_members m on p.id = m.advisor_id
join representatives r on m.user_id=r.user_id
where m.memeber_type='Advisor'
) t on users.advised_by  = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

/*Option 1 */

SELECT     * 
FROM       users usr 
INNER JOIN 
           ( 
                  SELECT p.id AS advisor_id 
                  FROM   advisors p 
                  JOIN   advisor_members m 
                  ON     p.id = m.advisor_id 
                  JOIN   representatives r 
                  ON     m.user_id=r.user_id 
                  WHERE  m.memeber_type='Advisor' ) T2 usr.advised_by = t2.advisor_id

/*Option2 -- */
SELECT     * 
FROM       users usr 
INNER JOIN advisors p 
ON         usr.advised_by=p.id 
JOIN 
           ( 
                  SELECT * 
                  FROM   advisor_members 
                  WHERE  m.memeber_type='Advisor') m 
ON         p.id = m.advisor_id 
JOIN       representatives r 
ON         m.user_id=r.user_id